# MvvmCross Xamarin.Android FloatingActionButton toggle visibility

Tags: android, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

This is my FloatingActionButton:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_retailer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility IsAddButtonVisible, Converter=Visibility" />
```

Its visibility property is bound via MvvmCross to IsAddButtonVisible:

```
private bool _isAddButtonVisible = true;
public bool IsAddButtonVisible
{
    get
    {
        return _isAddButtonVisible;
    }
    set
    {
        _isAddButtonVisible = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsAddButtonVisible);
    }
}
```

When I change the boolean value

```
ViewModel.IsAddButtonVisible = false;
```

...nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** when I bind using Visible, the toggling works

```
local:MvxBind="Visible IsAddButtonVisible"
```

but now I can't see any hide/show animations on the FloatingActionButton...

Comment: Is there any thing in your output, "Failed to create target binding for binding Visibility..."? What is your linker setting set to? Seen as you are using a bool type you could rather use the `Visible` Mvx custom binding option `local:MvxBind="Visible IsAddButtonVisible"`.

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r Thanks! I see nothing in my output, at least not where I usually see binding errors. Oh, when I use local:MvxBind="Visible IsAddButtonVisible", the toggling works :) But I don't see the usual animations on the button. It just appears and disappears. If I call hide() and show() manually I can see the animations so I think I've set up the button correctly. Any idea how to get those animations?

Comment: Interesting that you have no issues with the `Visible` binding but the   `Visibility` binding breaks with no errors. Out of curiosity what is your linker settings at when you do the build?

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r Do you mean my LinkerPleaseInclude file? I just noticed I have something inside there, it was a leftover from my experiments...

`public void Include(FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton)
        {
            floatingActionButton.Visibility = floatingActionButton.Visibility;
        }`

That was obviously not going to work...

Comment: It a settings in your cs proj. You can see it in Properties > Android Options > Linker (Tab) then Linking dropdown.

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r Linking is set to none with no additional supported encodings.

Comment: Thanks, it does not seem to be a linker issue.

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r No problem, thanks for helping me out! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to make use of a custom binding to use the method calls instead of the `Visibility` `ViewStates` changes.

---

Create the target binding that handles the executing the show and hide method calls based on the bool value you bind to.

```
public class FloatingActionButtonAnimateVisibleTargetBinding
    : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    protected FloatingActionButton View => (FloatingActionButton)Target;

    public FloatingActionButtonAnimateVisibleTargetBinding(FloatingActionButton target)
        : base(target)
    {
    }

    public override Type TargetType => typeof(bool);

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var isVisible = value.ConvertToBoolean();
        var floatingActionButton = target as FloatingActionButton;

        if (isVisible)
            floatingActionButton.Show();
        else
            floatingActionButton.Hide();
    }
```

}

Register the custom binding in your platform `Setup.cs`

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

    registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<FloatingActionButton>(
        "VisibleAnim",
        button => new FloatingActionButtonAnimateVisibleTargetBinding(button));
}
```

Then you should be able to make use of the binding in your XML

```
local:MvxBind="VisibleAnim IsAddButtonVisible"
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked. I had been looking at custom binders but I just started using MvvmCross since yesterday, I couldn't figure that out yet :)

Comment: Yes. That's one of the cool features of MvvmCross. Out of the box, it does a lot of stuff, but it also has hooks that allow you to do more advanced stuff directly with the native APIs.